# MobileServiceInvalidOperationException 500 - Internal server error while inserting into table

Tags: c#, azure, windows-8, microsoft-metro, azure-mobile-services

I want to make a sample app of uploading blob to azure storage. I have followed [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Upload-File-to-Windows-c9169190) and [this](http://www.nickharris.net/2012/11/how-to-upload-an-image-to-windows-azure-storage-using-mobile-services/), both the way throws me `MobileServiceInvalidOperationException` 500 - Internal server error. Please give me solution ASAP. Thanks.

Here is error log

> Error inserting: 
>   { AlbumId: 22,
>   Name: 'ff',
>   Description: 'ff', 
>   ThumbnailUrl: null,
>   ThumbnailFileName:
>   '73a594b1-1abb-476d-a1ce-73a12d6ee278_thumbnail.png', 
>    ImageUrl: null,
>   FileName: '73a594b1-1abb-476d-a1ce-73a12d6ee278.png', 
>   imageurl:
>   'https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/mypictures-undefined/undefined?se=2013-02-07T10%3A44%3A57Z&sr=b&sp=w&sig=qDBnnVOyo8XCNSUNJcn49IMcN4laDIgjZ8oM9TdiHBI%3D',
>   thumbnailurl:
>   'https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/mypictures-undefined/undefined?se=2013-02-07T10%3A44%3A57Z&sr=b&sp=w&sig=qDBnnVOyo8XCNSUNJcn49IMcN4laDIgjZ8oM9TdiHBI%3D'
>   }
>   {
>   [Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL
>   Server]The column name 'ImageUrl' is specified more than once in the
>   SET clause or column list of an INSERT. A column cannot be assigned
>   more than one value in the same clause. Modify the clause to make sure
>   that a column is updated only once. If this statement updates or
>   inserts columns into a view, column aliasing can conceal the
>   duplication in your code.] sqlstate: '42000', code: 264
>   }

Comment: Please post the code for your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with the reference of [this article](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/upload-images-to-storage-dotnet/). One advice from me, if you want a demo of uploading blob to Azure please visit that link don't waste your time in [MSDN sample](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/azuremobile/thread/code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Upload-File-to-Windows-c9169190).

Comment: did you notice the use of [DataMember(Name = "imageUrl")] in step 5 of the sample :)

Answer (score 5):

You've got two properties on the same (JavaScript) object that differ by case, but the Windows Azure SQL Database instance behind it isn't case-sensitive when it comes to column names.

It seems your C# class includes a property named `ImageUrl` (note case), then in the Insert script for your table (per [the reference you quoted](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Upload-File-to-Windows-c9169190)), you're doing `item.imageurl` in all lower case.

You could add the [DataMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to your C# property and you'd be ok, I suspect.

```
[DataMember(Name = "imageurl")]
public String ImageUrl { get; set; }
```

Same for `ThumbnailUrl`